# PyQt5: Setting data for a QStandardItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qstandarditem

If I construct a `QStandardItem` like so:

```
item = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item Name')
```

When this item is added to a `QStandardItemModel` model and is viewed in a `QTreeView` I get a cell that says `Item Name`. However, when I construct one like:

```
item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item.setData(123)
```

I get an an empty cell, but I can still recall the data by calling:

```
print(item.data())
```

and I will get the number `123`. How can I get the number to actually display in the cell?

Comment: `item.setData(str(123))`.

Comment: I need it to be an editable number though, and I can't rely on string to float conversions. I don't understand why if I set data directly from the model: `model.setData(model.index(0,1),123.987)` it will show the number, but if I do it on a `QStandardItem` it won't.

Comment: Also I just tried your suggestion, and it does not work either. Do you want me to paste a runnable example program? I just thought it might be too much for the question if it was a simple answer.

Comment: Forgot the role: `item.setData(str(123), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)` (which is the same as `item.setText(str(123))`). But also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41860415/984421).

Comment: You are a legend. So basically the data is there but to display it has to be displayed as a `QString`, which is done by specifying the role when setting the data. The role being the type of data you are assigning to the item (tooltip/display etc.) If you are happy to write this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument passed to the `QStandardItem` constructor sets the data for the [DisplayRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). So the equivalent method would be either:

```
item.setData(str(123), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
```

or:

```
item.setText(str(123))
```

But if you want to store the data in its orignal data-type, rather than converting it to a string first, you can use `QStyledItemDelegate` to control how the raw data is displayed:

```
class ItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            return '%08f' % value
        return value

view.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(view))
```